# Convert and Split Latlong Google Map flutter List

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

**I have Latlong Google Maps Flutter response like this:**

```
I/flutter (21690): [LatLng(-6.435887849941857, 106.85601130127908), LatLng(-6.4333171563046, 106.85805916786194), LatLng(-6.434791741881702, 106.8591035529971), LatLng(-6.436753407158089, 106.85817148536444)]
```

**I want to convert and split like this:**

```
[ [ -6.435887849941857, 106.85601130127908 ],[ -6.4333171563046, 106.85805916786194 ],[ -6.434791741881702, 106.8591035529971 ],[ -6.436753407158089, 106.85817148536444 ] ]
```

Thanks for all comments.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way thank to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) is mapping:

```
listOfLatLng.map((e) => [e.lat, e.lng]).toList()
```

*the other solutions*:

You can loop in your list and add to new list:

```
List finalList = [];
for (final element in listOfLatLng) {
  finalList.add([element.lat, element.lng]);
}
```

or `forEach` instead:

```
List finalList = [];
listOfLatLng.forEach((element) {
  finalList.add([element.lat, element.lng]);
});
```